# How to do Modal Bootstrap appear on bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to set up the bootstrap for modal appear in the browser's bottom?

https://jsfiddle.net/9fg7jsu3/

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Modal test</button>

    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">  
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
           </div>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I hope to have a result like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: better ask yourself how to achieve that without using modal. Modal is supposed to be detached, like new window. Proper div + styling should be enough.Or maybe  just use tooltips ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like that will do the work.
Now you need to play with paddings, margins and width to adjust your modal;

```
.modal-dialog {
   position:fixed;
   top:auto;
   right:auto;
   left:auto;
   bottom:0;
}
```

Use modal-dialog, not modal, otherwise the modal won't disappear if you click above it.

https://jsfiddle.net/9fg7jsu3/2/

Comment: Thank you @Mateusz Antoni Świątkowski. But when I click on the above modal it does not disappear, only if I click on the sides

Comment: You're welcome :) 
I edited solution with the right one, I guess :P
You're good tester :D

Cheers

Comment: His example is great just was not centralized. I updated the fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/9fg7jsu3/4/  Thank you again @Mateusz

Answer (score 11):

On the `<div class="modal-dialog" ...` use this,

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="align-items: flex-end;">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: this is the best way to do it, but bs4 when the modal comes into view they add ```display:block``` so u need to overwrite that as well. ```display:flex;```

Comment: align-items: flex-end is the solution

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

```
.modal-dialog {
  top: calc(100% - 300px); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this code worked perfectly:

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

In Bootstrap 5, the accepted solution changes the width without any specific reason.